# MySQL multiple query?

Tags: php, mysql

My table are:

```
exam_code     | roll |    name    | marks | negative_marks | 

model test 01   100    Md Kalam      88        3  

model test 01   101    Md Razzak     84        4

model test 02   100    Md Kalam      90        1

model test 01   102    Md Kalam      70        5
```

I want find-out Highest mark & Position according to exam_code by searching exam_code & roll

Final result will be like

```
Name:  Md Kalam
roll: 100
Exam Name: model test 01
Mark: 88
Highest mark: 88
Merit Postion: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE exam_code='$examcode' AND roll_number='$rollnumber'
ORDER BY marks desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: My query are    "SELECT * FROM (select MAX(marks) as highest FROM result GROUP BY exam_code) result WHERE  exam_code='$examcode' AND roll_number='$rollnumber' ORDER BY marks desc LIMIT 1"     its show Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource @Parkyprg

Comment: The ORDER BY marks DESC will arrange your result set starting with the biggest one. LIMIT 1 will provide you the first one (highest one).

Comment: but how can show it on table  $row[highest] as it?? & Merit postion will variable by $rollnumber so @Parkyprg